# JPA @ManyToOne map multiple fields pointing the same column

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-one

I need to map two fields from an entity (in this example, the entity *Colectivo*), that reference the same column on the related entity *TipoDominio*.
Is it possible?

Colectivo.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "TDM_TAC", referencedColumnName = "IDETDM")})
private TiposDominioMantenimiento tdmTac;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "TDN_ECO", referencedColumnName = "IDETDM")}) 
private TiposDominioMantenimiento tdnEco;
```

TipoDominio.java

```
@Id
@Column(name="IDETDM")
private BigDecimal ideTdm;
```

If not, how can I specify this?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You don't even need the `referencedColumnName`, it will default to the associated entity's `id`. Also, a singular `@JoinColumn` can be declared without the surrounding `@JoinColumns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JoinColumns` should only be used when your related entity has composite/multiple keys.

So as @crizzis mentioned, a single `@JoinColumn` should be enough for each attribute.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TDM_TAC")
private TiposDominioMantenimiento tdmTac;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TDN_ECO") 
private TiposDominioMantenimiento tdnEco;
```